# Replace iOS7 Keyboard by a Date Picker in TableViewController

Tags: ios, uidatepicker

I would like my textfield "DateText" to open a DatePicker (Year - Month - Day) with this type of value:

```
YYYY-MM-DD
```

Is there an easy way to change the keyboard?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can "replace" the keyboard by using the inputView property of the UITextField:

```
- (void) initializeTextFieldInputView {
    UIDatePicker *datePicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
    [datePicker addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(dateUpdated:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    self.textField.inputView = datePicker;
}

- (void) dateUpdated:(UIDatePicker *)datePicker {
    NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd"];
    self.textField.text = [formatter stringFromDate:datePicker.date];
}
```

UIDatePickers do not have a delegate like UIPickerViews so that is why an action must be added as if it were a UIButton. The `:` at the end of the selector declaration provides the UIDatePicker as a convenience to get the date when it has been changed. If you do not want to send an object in the method, you can get the UIDatePicker by referencing the UITextField's inputView:

```
UIDatePicker *datePicker = (UIDatePicker *)self.textField.inputView;
```

Lastly, when setting formats using NSDateFormatter, is good practice to create one method to return an NSDateFormatter object to make sure the format is consistent. At the very least, create a constant/macro once in your project that declares the format string.

**EDIT**

As asked by Pavan in the comments thread, if you want to add a done button above your keyboard, use the inputAccessoryView:

```
UIToolbar *toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] init];
UIBarButtonItem *doneButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Done" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(doneButtonWasPressed:)];
UIBarButtonItem *flexibleSeparator = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];
toolbar.items = @[flexibleSeparator, doneButton];
self.textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar;
```

**EDIT 2, SWIFT**

Seems like this Answer is quite outdated. Adding the implementation with Swift 3:

```
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.initializeTextFieldInputView()
}

func initializeTextFieldInputView() {
    // Add date picker
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker()
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .date
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(dateChanged(_:)), for: .valueChanged)
    self.textField.inputView = datePicker

    // Add toolbar with done button on the right
    let toolbar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 1))
    let flexibleSeparator = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .flexibleSpace, target: nil, action: nil)
    let doneButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .done, target: self, action: #selector(doneButtonPressed(_:)))
    toolbar.items = [flexibleSeparator, doneButton]
    self.textField.inputAccessoryView = toolbar
}

func dateChanged(_ datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    self.textField.text = formatter.string(from: datePicker.date)
}
```

You can also get the UIDatePicker by casting `inputView` in UITextField:

```
let datePicker = self.textField.inputView as? UIDatePicker
```

Comment: I put that in the .m or the .h file?

Comment: You put that in the .m file and then call `[self initializeTextFieldInputView];` in your `viewDidLoad` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Chris

Im beginning in iOS App Dev and that helped a Lot.

Comment: Chris - This is very helpful. Is there a way to add a done button on the right top corner to dismiss the datepicker ?

Comment: What is the point of setting the minuteInterval when selecting a date?

Comment: Setting the backgroundColor also doesn't make much sense. I would assume that most developers would be happy with the default. Probably even happier with the default.

Comment: @ErikB, this was an example from a personal project, which accounts for specific settings. Neither are necessary to answer the question, if that is what you are concerned with.

Comment: For me the doneButtonPressed method never get called. Any idea what might have gone wrong. I am setting the target as self for the button

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 2.0**

I found Chris's answer above helpful, but needed it in Swift.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Present UIDatePicker for date input
    let datePicker = UIDatePicker(frame: CGRectZero)
    datePicker.datePickerMode = .Date
    datePicker.addTarget(self, action: #selector(SettingsViewController.DateChanged), forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    self.fromTimeField.inputView = datePicker
}

 func timeChanged(datePicker: UIDatePicker) {
    let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
    formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
    self.fromTimeField.text = formatter.stringFromDate(datePicker.date)
```

Answer (score -1):

Enable UIDatePicker using Editing Did Begin action while creating TextField action.

```
- (IBAction)textFieldAction:(id)sender
{
    // Place your code for UIDatePicker
    [textField resignFirstResponder]; //add this line in the end.
}
```